# How to get a cumulative total within a select

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to get a cumulative total of the Tax + TurnoverExTAX from each order. Orders have x products per order. For 1 product it is easy to get the result. But with x products per order I have no idea how to get a cumulative total for each order row.

As you can see below the order 1901112055 does have 2 result rows. For TAX total = 7.28057851 + 3.80950413

How can I solve this query?
**Good Result = 11.09008264**

```
Orders_id   TAX     TurnoverExTax   
1901112055  7.28057851  34.66942149     
1901112055  3.80950413  18.14049587
```

When I do a GROUP BY orders_id I get 1 row but without the cumulation of the fields; TAX - TurnoverExTax

```
 Orders_id  TAX     TurnoverExTax   
 1901112055 7.28057851  34.66942149
```

Here simplified SELECT what I tried:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    orders.orders_id AS Orders_id,
            (orders_products.final_price) - (orders_products.final_price / ((orders_products.products_tax /100) + 1)) as TAX,
            (orders_products.final_price / ((orders_products.products_tax /100) + 1) ) AS TurnoverExTax
    FROM
            multi_ts24_nl.orders orders
    INNER JOIN
            multi_ts24_nl.orders_products AS orders_products
    ON
            orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
    WHERE
        orders.orders_id = 1901112055
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aggregation ( add `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` )

```
SELECT o.orders_id as Orders_id,
       SUM((p.final_price) -
           (p.final_price /
           ((p.products_tax / 100) + 1))) as Tax,
       SUM((p.final_price /
           ((p.products_tax / 100) + 1))) as TurnoverExTax
  FROM multi_ts24_nl.orders o
  JOIN multi_ts24_nl.orders_products AS p
    ON p.orders_id = o.orders_id
 WHERE o.orders_id = 1901112055
 GROUP BY Orders_id
```

and use shorter aliases for table names for simplicity